# How to split a data frame by the string name in the column and write respective outputs in a file?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> e=read.table("SG.genotypes.txt", header=TRUE)
> head(e)
              ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
1 snp_3_47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
2 snp_3_47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
3 snp_3_47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
4 snp_2_47616155       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
5 snp_2_47617504       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
6 snp_5_47617679       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
...
```

My data frame has many more snp_ names, but let's say how to split this example into 3 output files say named: chr_2,chr_3,chr_5

where chr_3 file for example will have just these lines:

```
              ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
1 snp_3_47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
2 snp_3_47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
3 snp_3_47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0
```

One way to do this would be to split column ID by string name and create two columns, but I wonder is there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can substring the 'ID' column and use that to `split`

```
lst1 <- split(df1, substr(df1$ID, 1, 5))
```

Note that if the number after the 'snp_' is greater than 9, it may be better to use `sub` instead of `substr`

```
lst1 <- split(df1, sub("^(snp_\\d+)_.*", "\\1", df1$ID))
names(lst1) <- sub("snp", "chr", names(lst1))
lst1
#$chr_2
#              ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
#4 snp_2_47616155       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
#5 snp_2_47617504       0       1       1       1       1       0       1

#$chr_3
#              ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
#1 snp_3_47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
#2 snp_3_47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
#3 snp_3_47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0       1

#$chr_5
#              ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
#6 snp_5_47617679       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
```

Loop through the `names` of the `list` and write it to `.csv` file

```
lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.csv(lst[[nm]], 
       file = paste0(nm, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("snp_3_47609552", "snp_3_47614413", "snp_3_47616151", 
 "snp_2_47616155", "snp_2_47617504", "snp_5_47617679"), HG00096 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HG00097 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HG00099 = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HG00100 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HG00101 = c(1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HG00102 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HG00103 = c(1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: a little problem is that chr_1 picks up entries for chr_11: > e=read.table("chr_1.txt", header=TRUE)
> head(e)
               ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
1 snp_11_70275774       0       0       1       0       1       0       2
2 snp_11_70275899       0       0       1       0       1       0       2

Comment: Can you please let me know how to prevent this?

Comment: @anikaM. Not clear about your comment.  If you want to `filter` only the 'snp' 2, 3, 5, then subset it and do the split i.e. `df2 <- subset(df1, substr(ID, 1, 5) %in% c("snp_2", "snp_3", "snp_5"))`

Comment: your script created for me all these files: chr_1.txt, chr_6.txt,chr_2.txt,chr_7.txt...which is what I want, and all created files look fine, except chr_1.txt, which has inside: lines like: snp_11_70275774 instead of  snp_1_70275774. How to solve this problem?

Comment: also chr_2.txt file has lines: snp_20_25177920 instead of snp_2_25177920

Comment: it's probably not good to hard code this substr(df1$ID, 1, 5), from 1 to 5 in string, because in other files I would have for example lines which look like snp_22_25177920, so that would be 6 spaces in string

Comment: @anikaM Glad that you come up with.  I would then use `split(df1, sub("^(snp_\\d+)_.*", "\\1", df1$ID))`

Comment: with this last command I got just one file which looks like this: > e=read.table("chr_CHR_POS.txt", header=TRUE)
> head(e)
           ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103 HG00104
1 snp_CHR_POS HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103 HG00104
2 snp_CHR_POS HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103 HG00104

Comment: well I got just one file, instead of 7 or so, and in that one file row names in ID column are basically substituted with: 1 snp_CHR_POS HG00096 HG00097...Something is off in that regex in split

Comment: @anikaM If you check my code on the data you showed , it is giving 3 files.

Comment: I see that you edited the previous version of split command by adding "\\1", and then it worked. Thank you